# Setting server response data to a variable to work with

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I am using a executePostHttpRequest function that looks exactly like the code posted below. Currently when I run the function I get a server response with the appropriate data but I am not sure how I can work with the response data? how do I store it in to a variable to work with?

**Javascript executePostHttpRequest**

```
function executePostHttpRequest(url, toSend, async) {
    console.log("====== POST request content ======");
    console.log(toSend);

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // new HttpRequest instance
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, async);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", toSend.length);
    xmlhttp.send(toSend);

    console.log("====== Sent POST request ======");
}
```

Here is what I am doing to execute it. Using Javascript

```
var searchCriteria = JSON.stringify({
    displayName : search_term
    });

    console.log("Search: "+searchCriteria) //Search: {"name":"John, Doe"} 

    var response = executePostHttpRequest("/web/search", searchCriteria, true);
    console.log(response) //undefined
```

So currently the console.log for response shows undefined. But if I take a look at the network tab on Chrome Dev Tools and look at the /web/search call I see a JSON string that came back that looks something like this.

```
[{"id":"1","email":"john.doe@dm.com","name":"John, Doe"}]
```

I'd like to be able to display the data from this response to a HTML page by doing something like this.

```
$("#id").html(response.id);
$("#name").html(response.name);
$("#email").html(response.email);
```

I tried taking another route and using Jquery POST instead by doing something like this.

```
var searchCriteria = JSON.stringify({
    displayName : search_term
    });

    console.log("Search: "+searchCriteria) //Search: {"name":"John, Doe"} 

    $.post("/web/search", {
        sendValue : searchCriteria
    }, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, d) {
                  console.log(d.name);
        });
            }, 'json').error(function() {
                  alert("There was an error searching users! Please contact administrator.");
        });
```

But for some reason when this runs I get the "There was an error" with no response from the server.

Could someone assist me with this? Thank you for taking your time to read it.

Comment: Eh, you're dividing `web` by `search` in the jQuery post method.

Comment: @JackieXu that was a typo sorry!

Comment: No prob. Another thing, in your vanilla JS version, you're calling a path from the 'root' domain, and in your jQuery version, you're calling a path relatively.

Comment: @JackieXu the URL I pass down thru a variable, for this post I added the url to show, but again that was a typo when I posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `executePostHttpRequest` function doesn't do anything with the data it's receiving. You would have to add an event listener to the `XMLHttpRequest` to get it:

```
function getPostData(url, toSend, async, method) {

    // Create new request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    // Set parameters
    xhr.open('POST', url, async)

    // Add event listener
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        // Check if finished
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

            // Do something with data
            method(xhr.responseText);

        }
    }
}
```

I've added the `method` parameter for you to add a function as parameter.

Here's an example of what you were trying to do:

```
function displayStuff(jsonString) {

    // Parse JSON string
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)

    // Loop over data
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        // Get element
        var element = data[i]

        // Do something with its attributes
        console.log(element.id)
        console.log(element.name)
    }

}

getPostData('/web/search', searchCriteria, true, displayStuff)
```

Comment: Hi Jackie Xu what exactly do you mean by the "method" function to add as parameter? Can't I just return the xhr.responseText? Could you perhaps supply me an example of this example being called for use? Thanks again! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Added an example. The reason why you can't just return xhr.responseText directly, is because you don't know when your request is done. That's why you have to add a callback method.

Comment: I seem to be getting this now "Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length" " no console data is set

Comment: You can remove the headers, it should work without them.